# Static code analysis for detecting passing a wchar_t* to BSTR

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-code-analysis, bstr

Since a `BSTR` is only a `typedef` for `wchar_t*` our code base has several (many?) places where string literals are passed to a method expecting a `BSTR` this can mess up with marshallers or anyone who tries to use any `BSTR` specific method (e.g. `SysStringLen`).

Is there any way to statically detect this type of misuse?

I tried compiling with VC10 `/Wall` and with static code analysis ***Microsoft All Rules*** but the following offending piece of code doesn't get flagged by either of them.

```
void foo(BSTR str)  
{
    std::cout << SysStringLen(str) << std::endl; 
}

int _tmain()
{
    foo(L"Don't do that");
}
```

---

**Update:** After trying to vandalize `wtypes.h` into detecting these kinds of transgressions I've given up.

I tried two paths, both of which I got to work with my sample program above but once I tried a real project they failed.

1. create a class named `BSTR` but since a `VARIANT` has a `BSTR` as a union member the new class couldn't have any constructors or assignment operators this broke every place were `NULL` was treated as a `BSTR`. I tried to replace `NULL` with a type that has conversion operators but after adding dozens of new operators (comparison, conversion etc.) I started to run into ambiguous calls and gave up.
2. I then tried the way suggested by @CashCow and @Hans (makeing `BSTR` a `typedef` to another type of pointer). That didn't work either, after adding `toBSTR` and `fromBSTR` methods and littering *comutil.h* (`_bstr_t`) and other places with conversions I finally got to the point where the compiler choked at headers produced from IDLs (default values are translated to literal wide strings).

In short I've given up on trying to achieve this on my own, if anyone knows of a code analysis tool that can help I would be very happy to hear about it.

Comment: BSTR may be such a typedef but that doesn't mean it's a null-terminated string. Its string representation actually beings with the 3rd wchar_t character, the first 2 being a length prefix (thus allowing length of up to 0xFFFF). They can contain embedded nulls. I think they are usually null-terminated.

Comment: @CashCow, not exactly, the length is placed *before* the actual data (this is what `SysStringLen` looks for) that's why it's incorrect to treat a `wchar_t*` as a `BSTR`.

Comment: Yes, the length is before the data. When you call SysAllocString it returns you the 5th byte. When you pass in a BSTR you pass in the address of the 5th allocated byte.

Comment: @CashCow I understand all this, what is your point?

Comment: Making BSTR an alias for wchar_t* was quite intentional.  One possible approach is to carefully make a backup copy of the SDK's wtypes.h header and edit the definition to, say, a pointer to an empty struct.  Rebuild your projects and the compiler will complain loudly wherever a wchar_t* is substituted.

Comment: @HansPassant that would cause many other compilation errors e.g. where a `BSTR` is passed to `wcscmp`.

Comment: Yup, that was the intentional part.  You can't have it both ways.

Comment: You write an overload of wcscmp that takes your new BSTR so that code compiles. Then you take it out again.

Comment: @CashCow and for every other string function that is used... I suppose that would work.

Comment: @HansPassant I've updated the question with the (lack of) progress I made. Any further suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It's unfortunate that `typedef enum class BSTRchar : wchar_t {} *BSTR;` doesn't work either... scoped enums don't have implicit upcast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [Coverity](http://www.coverity.com/products/static-analysis.html) claims to detect these sorts of vulnerabilities.  I remember them mentioning COM stuff specifically when they demo'd to a company I worked for.

Their [datasheet](http://www.coverity.com/library/pdf/Coverity_DS_CWMapping_cpp.pdf) certainly seems to imply they check for classes of improper BSTR usage.  They have a demo-period; you could try it and see if it flags your sample input.

Comment: After checking it out I see that `COM.BSTR.CONV` detects this pattern, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to change your methods to take _bstr_t or CComBSTR instead?

If not then as a literal is technically a const wchar_t *, if there is a compiler setting to not allow literal->non-const pointer conversion then you can do that.

Failing that, there is a possibility of modifying the definition of BSTR to be unsigned short *. Then if you build all your source, you will get compiler errors wherever a literal is being passed in and you can fix all this code. Then I would suggest changing it back...

Comment: Option 2 (prevent conversions from `const wchar_t*`) isn't enough since not all instances are literal strings. Option 3 (`typedef unsigned short* BSTR`) wouldn't work since we sometimes pass a `BSTR` to  `wcscmp` (et al.) which doesn't accept `unsigned short*`

Answer (score 1):

You may try compiling with Clang, it's static/dynamic analysis may find what you are looking for.

Comment: Does Clang support compiling Microsoft specific C++?

Comment: Pretty sure it does now, and continually improving.

Answer (score 0):

Overload all functions with the BSTR and forward them with the appropriate conversion.

```
void foo( BSTR str )
{
    std::cout << SysStringLen(str) << std::endl; 
}

void foo( const WCHAR *str )
{
    foo( SysAllocString( str ));
}

int _tmain()
{
    foo( L"don't do this" );
    return 0;
}
```

Or, to generate compiler errors, change all of the parameter types from BSTR to something else and look for the errors:

```
typedef UINT bar;

void foo( bar _str )
{
    // make the compiler happy below
    BSTR str = (BSTR)_str;
    std::cout << SysStringLen(str) << std::endl;
}

int _tmain()
{
    foo( L"don't do this" );
    foo( (bar)42 );
    return 0;
}
```

**error C2664: 'foo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t [14]' to 'bar'**

I assume the C2664 error and the 'const wchar_t[]' type identified by the compiler is what you want the compiler to find for every internal call made to the function using the BSTR?